# Script for targeting platforms (not browsers)

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to get a straight answer for this, not sure what I'm doing wrong, but have been searching for a solution for over a month.

I need to call separate stylesheets, pending on the platform (not browser). I have a script I've found that's supposed to do that, but it's not working.

The site is fish-fry.com/dev

the script, which I've placed in my head is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Different CSS depending on OS (mac/pc)- © Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice must stay intact for use
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
***********************************************/

var csstype="external" //Specify type of CSS to use. "Inline" or "external"

var mac_externalcss='http://www.fish-fry.com/dev/wp-content/themes/FISH-FRY-MUSIC-AND-SOUND-CUSTOM-THEME/style.css' //if "external", specify Mac css file here
var pc_externalcss='http://www.fish-fry.com/dev/wp-content/themes/FISH-FRY-MUSIC-AND-SOUND-CUSTOM-THEME/style-windows.css' //if "external", specify PC/default css file here

///////No need to edit beyond here////////////

var mactest=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac")!=-1
if (csstype=="inline"){
document.write('<style type="text/css">')
if (mactest)
document.write(mac_css)
else
document.write(pc_css)
document.write('</style>')
}
else if (csstype=="external")
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+ (mactest? mac_externalcss : pc_externalcss) +'">')

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd run that script through [jslint.com](http://jslint.com) to start with.
There seems to be quite a few formatting errors.

Also check [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/operatin.htm) out.
Perhaps the useragent is not the place to be checking?

**Note**: navigator.**appVersion**.indexOf("Win")

Comment: Thanks for tip @dibs, seems like a good resource to have in your pocket!